# Chrome Array.sorting numbers out of order

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting

I was trying to sort an array of divs so that if `a` is below or to the left of `b`, `a` is before `b`.

After a couple hours in CodePen, I realized that if an array is ten or more items in length, Chrome will sort the items out of order, at least with this compare function:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return -1;
});
```

Chrome returns:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5]
```

[See on CodePen](http://codepen.io/nth-chile/pen/QvEKbN?editors=0012)

If you log a and b inside the sort function, it becomes obvious why it happens--it's just the algorithm Chrome uses. I know people use return a-b etc ... but let's turn to the following function ... The array is of jQuery objects containing divs. I want a to come before b if a is below or to the left of b. Any help??

EDIT: In response to some answers here, I rewrite function to output either `1`, `-1`, or `0`. Still, I get unwanted results. See how in the output, the first object's `right` property is greater than the second's `left` property, and the first object's `top` property is lower than the second's `bottom`. According to the compare function, they should be in the opposite order.

```js
var array = [
  
  {
    bottom:1181.8854675292969,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:72.39583396911621,
    top:910.8854675292969,
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1181.3750305175781,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:1132.3750305175781
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1182.6042175292969,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:349.3958435058594,
    top:1021.6042175292969
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1181.3750305175781,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:626.3958435058594,
    top:1132.3750305175781
  },
   
  {
    bottom:1133.2292175292969,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:632.3958435058594,
    top:1132.2292175292969
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:1022.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:460.3958435058594,
    top:1022.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:466.3958435058594,
    right:571.3958435058594,
    top:1022.0208435058594,
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1016.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:911.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1016.2395935058594,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:515.3958435058594,
    top:800.2395935058594
  },
   
  {
    bottom:1016.2395935058594,
    left:521.3958740234375,
    right:626.3958740234375,
    top:800.2395935058594
  },  
  
  {
    bottom:906.0208435058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:183.3958339691162,
    top:801.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.6041870117188,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:72.39583396911621,
    top:634.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:795.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:690.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:404.3958435058594,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:410.3958435058594,
    right:515.3958435058594,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:521.3958740234375,
    right:626.3958740234375,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:683.3750152587891,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:634.3750152587891
  },
  
  {
    bottom:684.6041870117188,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:349.3958435058594,
    top:523.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:684.6041870117188,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:570.3958435058594,
    top:523.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:629.0208435058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:183.3958339691162,
    top:524.0208435058594
  },
    
  {
    bottom:518.2395935058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:128.3958339691162,
    top:302.2395935058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:517.8854217529297,
    left:134.39584350585938,
    right:405.3958435058594,
    top:246.8854217529297
  },
  
  {
    bottom:518.604175567627,
    left:411.3958435058594,
    right:626.3958435058594,
    top:357.60417556762695
  }
];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right)
   return 1;
 if(a.bottom > b.top || a.left < b.right)
  return -1;
 return 0;
});

console.log(array[4],array[8]);
```

**EDIT:** Found a workaround for my purposes. I used `forEach` to compare the items to each other and increment `z-index` based on vertical and then horizontal order:

```
function setTileZIndex() {
        var $tiles = $('.grid__item__wrap');
        var coords = [];
        $tiles.each(function(index) {
            var topLeft = $(this).offset();
            var obj = {
                bottom: topLeft.top + $(this).height(),
                left: topLeft.left,
                top: topLeft.top,
                right: topLeft.left + $(this).width(),
                $this: $(this),
                z: 9999
            };
            coords.push(obj);
        });

        coords.forEach(function(a) {
            coords.forEach(function(b) {
                if (a.bottom < b.top)
                    b.z += 4;
                if (a.left > b.right)
                    b.z += 1;
            })
        });

        coords.forEach(function(elt) {
            elt.$this.css('z-index', elt.z);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Provide whole code, but inside code snippet, not codepen.

Comment: please add the original data, you like to sort.

Comment: Can you include `coords` array and expected result at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 ;)

Comment: @nth-chile What is expected result?

Comment: Is `[
  {
    "bottom": 906,
    "left": 23,
    "right": 183,
    "top": 801
  },
  {
    "bottom": 1181,
    "left": 23,
    "right": 72,
    "top": 910
  }
]` correct order? What is purpose of second `if` condition `if(a.bottom > b.top || a.left < b.right)`?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, in my haste I probably didn't explain thoroughly. The only thing required of the resulting array is that, if a box is completely above OR to the right of another (`a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right`), it should come after the other box. I will use this array to assign `z-indexes` so the 3d hover effect will make sense and not go behind adjacent boxes that it should be in front of.

Comment: @nth-chile Are you sure the condition matches the expected result?

Comment: @nth-chile `array.sort((a, b) => a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right ? 1 : -1)`?

Comment: This is what I had originally. Same results ... I think @Thiago Barcala has pointed out the problem. Now to find a solution!

Comment: @nth-chile _"Now to find a solution!"_ Have you tried condition at Answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142371/discussion-between-nth-chile-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function must return:

- negative: when the first element should come before the second
- zero: when the order between elements doesn't matter
- positive: when the second element should come before the first.

Returning always -1 causes a random result.

I'm afraid it is not possible to do what you are trying to do, because the compare function must be consistent through all elements in the array. With the compare function you are using, it is possible to have `f(a, b) = -1`, and `f(b, a) = -1`, which is inconsistent: either `a` or `b` should come first.

Comment: Hmm so I tried adding

`if(a.bottom > b.top || a.left < b.right)
  {return -1}; return 0;` without luck. Or would it be something else?

Comment: Accepted because this would make sense as to why it is not working. I can't think of a solution though. I think I am going to try asking _how many_ items are above/to the right of each element, and set `z-index` based on that.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

It seems you've over-simplified in your original question. Here's an updated answer:

> I want a to come before b if a is below or to the left of b. Any help??

In that case, make sure you're comparing the same edges of each object – ie compare `a.left` with `b.left`, and `a.bottom` with `b.bottom` ...

```js
const data = [
  { bottom:1181, left:23, right:72, top:910, },
  { bottom:906, left:23, right:183, top:801 },
  { bottom:1181, left:78, right:183, top:1132 },
  { bottom:1182, left:189, right:349, top:1021 },
  { bottom:1133, left:355, right:632, top:1132 },
  { bottom:795, left:78, right:183, top:690 },
  { bottom:1181, left:355, right:626, top:1132 },
  { bottom:1127, left:78, right:183, top:1022 },
  { bottom:1127, left:355, right:460, top:1022 },
  { bottom:1127, left:466, right:571, top:1022, },
  { bottom:1016, left:78, right:183, top:911 },
]

data.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.left < b.left || a.bottom < b.bottom)
    return -1
  else if (a.right > b.right || a.top > b.top)
    return 1
  else
    return 0
})

console.log(data)
// [ { bottom: 906, left: 23, right: 183, top: 801 },
//   { bottom: 1181, left: 23, right: 72, top: 910 },
//   { bottom: 795, left: 78, right: 183, top: 690 },
//   { bottom: 1016, left: 78, right: 183, top: 911 },
//   { bottom: 1127, left: 78, right: 183, top: 1022 },
//   { bottom: 1182, left: 189, right: 349, top: 1021 },
//   { bottom: 1133, left: 355, right: 632, top: 1132 },
//   { bottom: 1181, left: 78, right: 183, top: 1132 },
//   { bottom: 1127, left: 355, right: 460, top: 1022 },
//   { bottom: 1181, left: 355, right: 626, top: 1132 },
//   { bottom: 1127, left: 466, right: 571, top: 1022 } ]
```

---

**Original answer**

I'm certain this has been answered somewhere else on this site, but your comparator **must** return `-1`, `0`, and `1` values to get an intended result

- `-1` moves the `a` to the left of `b`
- `1` moves the `a` to the right of `b`
- `0` results in neither `a` or `b` changing positions

```js
let sorted = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].sort((a,b) => {
  if (a < b)
    return -1
  else if (a > b)
    return 1
  else
    return 0
})

console.log(sorted)
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

---

Or use super-terse but harder-to-read chained ternary expressions

```js
let sorted = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].sort((a,b) =>
  a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
)

console.log(sorted)
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

---

Keep in mind, elements in the array are not necessarily compared in an order you might expect – ie, don't expect `compare(0,1)` then `compare(1,2)`, then `compare(2,3)`, etc

```js
let sorted = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].sort((a,b) => {
  console.log(a,b)
  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0)
})
// 0 10
// 0 5
// 10 5
// 2 5
// 3 5
// 4 5
// 1 5
// 6 5
// 9 5
// 8 5
// 7 5
// 0 2
// 2 3
// 3 4
// 4 1
// 3 1
// 2 1
// 0 1
// 6 7
// 7 8
// 8 9
// 9 10

console.log(sorted)
//=> [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Comment: _"your comparator must return `-1`, `0`, and `1` values to get an intended result"_ Can you include precise description of what `-1`, `0`, and `1` result in as to `a`, `b` and returned array at Answer?

Comment: while the answer is right, chrome has a different sorting algo for array length >= 10. chrome is for returning the same value not stable.

Comment: @NinaScholz interesting. as long as the comparator is defined properly tho, there's no outstanding bug, is there?

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry, in my haste I probably didn't explain thoroughly. The only
>   thing required of the resulting array is that, if a box is completely
>   above OR to the right of another
>
> `(a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right)`
>
> it should come after the other box.

One set of conditions are

```
a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right ? 1 : -1
```

as verified by `.reduceRight()` call.

```js
var coords = [
  
  {
    bottom:1181.8854675292969,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:72.39583396911621,
    top:910.8854675292969,
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1181.3750305175781,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:1132.3750305175781
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1182.6042175292969,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:349.3958435058594,
    top:1021.6042175292969
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1181.3750305175781,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:626.3958435058594,
    top:1132.3750305175781
  },
   
  {
    bottom:1133.2292175292969,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:632.3958435058594,
    top:1132.2292175292969
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:1022.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:460.3958435058594,
    top:1022.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1127.0208435058594,
    left:466.3958435058594,
    right:571.3958435058594,
    top:1022.0208435058594,
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1016.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:911.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:1016.2395935058594,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:515.3958435058594,
    top:800.2395935058594
  },
   
  {
    bottom:1016.2395935058594,
    left:521.3958740234375,
    right:626.3958740234375,
    top:800.2395935058594
  },  
  
  {
    bottom:906.0208435058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:183.3958339691162,
    top:801.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.6041870117188,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:72.39583396911621,
    top:634.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:795.0208435058594,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:690.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:404.3958435058594,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:410.3958435058594,
    right:515.3958435058594,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:794.0208435058594,
    left:521.3958740234375,
    right:626.3958740234375,
    top:689.0208435058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:683.3750152587891,
    left:78.39583587646484,
    right:183.39583587646484,
    top:634.3750152587891
  },
  
  {
    bottom:684.6041870117188,
    left:189.39584350585938,
    right:349.3958435058594,
    top:523.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:684.6041870117188,
    left:355.3958435058594,
    right:570.3958435058594,
    top:523.6041870117188
  },
  
  {
    bottom:629.0208435058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:183.3958339691162,
    top:524.0208435058594
  },
    
  {
    bottom:518.2395935058594,
    left:23.39583396911621,
    right:128.3958339691162,
    top:302.2395935058594
  },
  
  {
    bottom:517.8854217529297,
    left:134.39584350585938,
    right:405.3958435058594,
    top:246.8854217529297
  },
  
  {
    bottom:518.604175567627,
    left:411.3958435058594,
    right:626.3958435058594,
    top:357.60417556762695
  }
];


// a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right ? a.bottom > b.top || a.left < b.right ? 0 : 1 : -1
coords.sort((a, b) => a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right ? 1 : -1);

console.log(coords);

coords.reduceRight((a, b) => {console.log(a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right); return b});
```

Comment: When I run this code with the array I use in my answer, and I `console.log(coords[4], coords[8])` (as these are the problem ones), logged is:
`Object {`
  `bottom: 1133.2292175292969,`
  `left: 355.3958435058594,`
  `right: 632.3958435058594,`
  `top: 1132.2292175292969`
`} Object {`
`  bottom: 1016.0208435058594,`
`  left: 78.39583587646484,`
`  right: 183.39583587646484,`
`  top: 911.0208435058594`
`}`

Same results ... but there must be something wrong with the function because the order of the initial array affects the output. I think @Thaiago Barcala is on to something.

Comment: @nth-chile Not sure what you mean. _"The only thing required of the resulting array is that, if a box is completely above OR to the right of another `(a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right)` it should come after the other box."_ The condition `(a.bottom < b.top || a.left > b.right)` is `true` for each `a,b` in reverse order, as `.reduceRight()` verifies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison function that will work for you.

```js
var arr = [15, 4, 11, 19, 11];

function compareFn(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : a === b ? 0 : -1;
}

var sorted = arr.sort(compareFn);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test the code in Chrome and for example in Edge. In Crome, the sort is not stable, if a return value is the same for all comparisons.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array.sort(function(a, b) { return 0; });
console.log(array); // Chrome: [5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                    // Edge:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array.sort(function(a, b) { return 1; });
console.log(array); // Chrome: [5, 10, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2]
                    // Edge:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array.sort(function(a, b) { return -1; });
console.log(array); // Chrome: [0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5]
                    // Edge:   [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```